# "cannot infer type for `_`" when using map on iter in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, inference

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to initialise a 2D array of booleans with random true/false values but the compiler doesn't seem to be able to infer the types I need; I am just wondering what I need to specify for the inference engine to be able to resolve this.

```
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    let mut grid = [[false; 10]; 10];
    grid.iter_mut().map(|row| { [false; 10].iter().map(|_| { rand::random() }).collect() });
}
```

Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f63190bffe1354dd769f518a6654b883&version=stable&backtrace=0) (without `rand::random()`)

The error I'm getting is

```
   | grid.iter_mut().map(|row| { [false; 10].iter().map(|_| { rand::random() }).collect() });
   |                 ^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
```

Comment: Well, you may wish to read the documentation on [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect). Once you understand why the closure's return type cannot be inferred, you are still left with being unable to collect into a sized array. Can you rephrase the question accordingly afterwards?

Comment: As a performance aside, you probably want to grab a `Rng` and reuse it, instead of grabbing the thread-local RNG over and over.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the type `[T; 10]` implements `Rand` where `T: Rand`, you can use `rand::random()` directly:

```
extern crate rand;

fn main() {
    let grid: [[bool; 10]; 10] = rand::random();
    println!("{:#?}", grid);
}
```

---

As for why type inference is failing in your example - here's something slightly simpler that illustrates the problem:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = [false; 10];
    let mapped = arr.iter_mut().map(|_| rand::random()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", arr);
    println!("{:?}", mapped);
}
```

Gives the error:

```
error[E0282]: unable to infer enough type information about `_`
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |         let mapped = arr.iter_mut().map(|_| rand::random()).collect();
  |             ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
  |
  = note: type annotations or generic parameter binding required
```

So we can specify the type:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = [false; 10];
    let mapped = arr.iter_mut().map(|_| rand::random()).collect::<[bool; 10]>();
    println!("{:?}", arr);
    println!("{:?}", mapped);
}
```

Note the use of the *"turbofish"* operator `::<>` after collect to specify the type to collect into, in this case `::<[bool; 10]>`. Unfortunately here the compiler will complain:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[_; 10]: std::iter::FromIterator<bool>` is not satisfied
```

So what is `std::iter::FromIterator<bool>`? Well, consider the `collect` function's definition:

```
fn collect<B>(self) -> B
    where B: FromIterator<Self::Item>
```

This means whatever type you are collecting into needs to implement `FromIterator<Self::Item>`. Arrays do not, unfortunately, implement `FromIterator` - but there are many possible types that do, for instance `Vec`, `VecDeque`, `HashSet`, `BTreeSet` and so on. So we can modify the example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = [false; 10];
    let mapped = arr.iter_mut().map(|_| rand::random()).collect::<Vec<bool>>();
    println!("{:?}", arr);
    println!("{:?}", mapped);
}
```

However, this might not give you the result you were hoping for:

```
[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
[true, false, false, true, true, false, true, false, true, true]
```

So what gives? Why wasn't the `arr` mutated even though it was declared mutable, and we used `iter_mut`? The reason is that `map` produces a *new* object from the existing one - it doesn't map "in-place". If you really wanted to map in-place, you *could* use the following:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = [false; 10];
    let mapped = arr.iter_mut().map(|b| *b = rand::random()).collect::<Vec<()>>();
    println!("{:?}", arr);
    println!("{:?}", mapped);
}
```

Yielding

```
[true, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, true]
[(), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]
```

However, this use of iterators is considered unidiomatic (not to mention confusing) - the idiomatic way would be to use a `for` loop:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = [false; 10];
    for b in &mut arr {
        *b = rand::random();
    }
    println!("{:?}", arr);
}
```

```
[false, true, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, false]
```

Much better. Of course in this particular case, my first example is probably the way to go.